# 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/shah - You do not have permission to publish "shah". Are you logged in as the correct user?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I am trying to create npm reactjs component library. I have been working through all the steps but stuck at npm publish.

Please see the below error screenshot for which I am unable to find a solution on google after trying more than an hour(The error message is not that accurate IMHO or maybe I am not able to catch it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgPAX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shah` package already exists and `npm` is telling you that you don't have permissions to publish new versions to it. Change your package name and you'll be fine.